# passing props to component during routing

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchDocument from './components/searchDocument';
import CreateRequest from './components/createRequest';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                        <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
                        <Route path='/create' component={CreateRequest} />
                        <Route path='/searchDocument' component{SearchDocument} />
                        <Route path='/upload' component={UploadDocument} />
                        <Route path='/search' component={Search} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

I am new to react router.I want to pass `props` through route to create request component.I tried different methods to pass props but that doesn't work.Can anyone please suggest, how to send `props` to component and how to handle them in that component.Above is my code.Thanks in advance

Comment: Checkout the documentation for [Route render-func](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func). You could use the `render` method instead of `component`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the `render` prop instead of the `component`.

From the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func):

> Instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the location matches. The render prop receives all the same route props as the component render prop.

And an example with your code will look like this:

```
<Route path='/searchDocument' render={(props) => <SearchDocument yourNewProp={yourNewProp} {...props} />} />
```